# Django: formats of urlpatterns in urls.py

Tags: django, url

I noticed that in Django there are two formats of `urlpatterns` in file `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(...),
    url(...),
]
```

and

```
urlpatterns = pattern('',
    url(...),
    url(...),
)
```

The first is a list of `url` instances, and the second invokes the `pattern` module with an empty string and a number of `url` instances as parameters.

1. What is the difference between the two?
2. What is the purpose of an empty string in the second format?
3. Which one is recommended to use?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In Django 1.8+, urlpatterns should simply be a list of `url()`s. This new syntax actually works in 1.7 as well.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(...),
    url(...),
]
```

The old syntax using `pattern` [is deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-10) in Django 1.8, and is removed in Django 1.10.

```
urlpatterns = pattern('',
    url(...),
    url(...),
)
```

With the old syntax, you could provide a prefix. The example given [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#patterns) is

```
urlpatterns = patterns('news.views',
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/$', 'year_archive'),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/$', 'month_archive'),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]+)/$', 'article_detail'),
)
```

However, using strings arguments for the view is now deprecated as well, and you should provide the callable instead.

Answer (score 8):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#patterns), `patterns` is:

> A function that takes a prefix, and an arbitrary number of URL
>   patterns, and returns a list of URL patterns in the format Django
>   needs.
>
> The first argument to `patterns()` is a string `prefix`.

It also provides an example of why you might want to use it:

> ```
> from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
>
> urlpatterns = patterns('',
>     url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/$', 'news.views.year_archive'),
>     url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/$', 'news.views.month_archive'),
>     url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]+)/$', 'news.views.article_detail'),
> )
> ```
>
> In this example, each view has a common prefix – `'news.views'`.
>   Instead of typing that out for each entry in `urlpatterns`, you can
>   use the first argument to the `patterns()` function to specify a
>   prefix to apply to each view function.
>
> With this in mind, the above example can be written more concisely as:
>
> ```
> from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
>
> urlpatterns = patterns('news.views',
>     url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/$', 'year_archive'),
>     url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/$', 'month_archive'),
>     url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]+)/$', 'article_detail'),
> )
> ```

---

However, note that this function is deprecated:

> **Deprecated since version 1.8:**
>
> `urlpatterns` should be a plain list of `django.conf.urls.url()` instances instead.

Note that [the explanation as to why](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#django-conf-urls-patterns) includes (with good reason, clearly!):

> Thus `patterns()` serves little purpose and is a burden when teaching
>   new users (answering the newbie’s question *"why do I need this empty
>   string as the first argument to `patterns()`?"*).

Comment: It's worth noting that string-references to view functions and the `patterns()` function are deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10. To avoid deprecation warnings, use a plain list instead.