# Where has patterns gone in django 1.10?

Tags: python, django

python 2.7, django 1.10, windows10 x64, pycharm5.0.5

I want to use admin management
 The codes in the `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from Net.welcome import req
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = {
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^Net/welcome/$', req),
   # url(r'^login/', login),
}
# or like this:
urlpatterns = patterns{
    url(r'^admin/', include('admin.site.urls')),
    url(r'^Net/welcome/$', req),
    # url(r'^login/', login),
}
```

I can not import module some like `from django.conf.urls.default import *`,because no default module in urls at django 1.10

Where has `patterns` has gone?

In the `setting.py` ,I had add `django.contrib.admin` and `django.contrib.auth`.

Comment: Deprecated since 1.8. [supposed](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/224123/djangoconfurlspatterns_has_been_deprecated_for/) to be removed in 2.0 but maybe they did it a bit early. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474285/django-formats-of-urlpatterns-in-urls-py

Comment: If you used that on `1.9`, you would have seen : *django.conf.urls.patterns() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10. Update your urlpatterns to be a list of django.conf.urls.url() instances instead.*

Comment: @PaulRooney The version scheme was changed, and 2.0 was renamed to 1.10. It was always supposed to be removed 2 versions after 1.8 in accordance with to the deprecation policy.

Comment: ok thanks for the info I was only guessing.

Comment: @Atsukon `django.conf.urls.default` was removed long before `patterns` was, in 1.6. The functions were moved to the root module in `django.conf.urls`.