# ViewDoesNotExist at /myapp/ Could not import

Tags: django-views, django-urls, python-2.x, django-1.8

I'm tasked with a migration from 1.8 to 1.11, but I need to ensure I can at least get this site running in 1.8 (it's not my code) before the upgrade. What is a trivial issue, is nevertheless preventing me from bringing up this site. I'm to restructure the code in a more djangothonic way, and am struck on the views:

The structure so far has been reformatted like so (omitting other folders/files)

```
mysite-closed
    -> mysite
        __init__.py
        -> mysite
            __init__.py
            -> settings.py
            urls.py # (1 below)
        -> myapp
            __init__.py
            urls.py # (2 below)
            -> views
                __init__.py
                -> basic.py
```

**mysite.mysite.urls.py (1)**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)), 
    (r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
    (r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')), 
)
```

**mysite.myapp.urls.py (2)**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views.basic', 
    (r'^$', 'costs'),
    (r'^about/', 'about'),
)
```

**settings.py**

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'tcosite.urls'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'tco',
)
```

**basic.py**

```
def costs(request):
'''
load of code
'''
    pass
```

I've taken care of the **init**.py file in the folders, but I suspect I'm overlooking something perhaps in the settings.py. Are there certain parameters in settings which could influence the importing of the views module? I've tried various permutations in the path for the urls.py, such as:

```
myapp.views.basic
mysite.myapp.views.basic
views.basic
```

The error messages I receive are:

```
ViewDoesNotExist at /myapp/
Could not import myapp.views.basic.costs. View does not exist in module myapp.views.basic.
```

With `mysite.myapp.views.basic` I get:

```
ImportError at /myapp/
No module named myapp.views
```

With `views.basic` I get:

```
ImportError at /tco/
No module named views
```

I've also moved my views folder to one level lower, still no success.

Comment: Did you import your views?? in myapp `urls.py`

Comment: @Akash It's under patterns('myapp.views.basic', ...

Comment: pymat you are having two urls but none of them calling your views

Comment: yes that's right.

Answer (score 0):

try these docs [Django 1.8 urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#patterns) and your problem is already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474285/django-formats-of-urlpatterns-in-urls-py)

Comment: Correct me if 'Im wrong, but this would be legitimate answer if I were using Django 1.11, for example. My question pertains to Django 1.8.

Comment: oops I forget your version

Comment: Pymat why don't you use the latest version of Django?I can't figure out exactly where your error is.I don't have experience in below 1.9,

Comment: Because before I migrate, I need to get this code working i.e. the site is running locally. Then from then I can migrate.